# How can I get Digix Dao ethereum tokens off of an exchange (coinbase)

Tags: tokens, dao, exchanges, digix

Basically what happened is that I tried to trade 30 ether for digix dao tokens using shapeshift. I entered an ethereum address on myetherwallet as the destination address where I wanted the DGD to go since I would actually have access to the tokens there. Instead, shapeshift apparently had problems with the trade initially so I emailed them. After 3 days, they finally sent the DGD tokens but they didn't send them to the address I provided, but instead sent them to the address I originally sent the ether from, which is a coinbase wallet. WTF why do you think I wanted you to send them to a different address?

I can now see when looking up this ethereum address on etherscan that the DGD tokens are there, but I don't have access to them because these idiots sent my tokens to an exchange. Basically what I want to know is how can I get these tokens off of my coinbase address and into the myetherwallet address where I wanted them to go originally? Since coinbase doesn't keep track of any token balances so these tokens will not show up in my coinbase account. Is there anyone I could contact at coinbase who might be able to help? I already tried sending a regular support ticket to coinbase and that got me nowhere, which doesn't surprise me because I'm pretty sure it's not every day someone has a problem like this.

The thing I'm most concerned about is not being able to collect the quarterly rewards that you get with the digix dao tokens if they remain on an exchange which is the main reason I want to get them off.

TL, DR: I have DGD tokens in an ethereum wallet on coinbase. How do I transfer these tokens to a different ethereum wallet? If you want to know why I have DGD tokens in a coinbase wallet, you would actually have to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

at the moment you will not get any tokens from Coinbase, because they are not supporting this kind of coins.
You have it there but until they implement tokens on their Ethereum wallet, there is nothing you (or they) can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the US or UK, you can sue coinbase for possession of your property if they do not wish to help you out (most likely). Even though they control the private key, it's is still your property.

This is a weird area of law without much precedent set. Coinbase is not exactly the most reputable of companies to be dealing with, especially when it comes to technical support. They have willfully chosen to neglect basic customer service as a means to quell legal issues, so I think the legal route may be the best way to proceed if they give you a hard time.